# Cannot read item in nested array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a nested array inside a list like the following:

{total_results, page, results [id, species_guess, observed_on_details {date, week, month, hour, year}]}

I am trying to get just the id, species_guess, and date using forEach.

```
function observationSummary2(data) {
  data.results.forEach(element =>
    console.log('#' + data.results.id +
     " - " + data.results.species_guess +
      ' (' + data.results.observed_on_details.date + ')')
  );
}
```

This is saying " Cannot read property 'date' of undefined ". I have tried using a for loop like this and it worked just fine.

```
 for (let i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
    console.log('#' + data.results[i].id + " - " + data.results[i].species_guess + ' (' + data.results[i].observed_on_details.date + ')');
  }
```

Can anyone tell me where am I doing wrong here, sorry I am still new at this language.

Comment: In the `.forEach` you need to use `element`, not `data`. `element` is the current object, and equates to the `for` loop's `data.results[i]`

Comment: Each element is available as `element`. You are trying to access each element’s properties on the array of elements, which won’t work.

Comment: Because you need to iterate down the nested array properties `data.results.forEach((result) => {
 result.observed_on_details.forEach((observed_on_detail) => {
  console.log(observed_on_detail.date);
 });
})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use foreach as follow

```js
function observationSummary2(data) {
  data.results.forEach(element =>
    console.log('#' + element.id +
     " - " + element.species_guess +
      ' (' + element.observed_on_details.date + ')')
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
function observationSummary2(data) {
    data.results.forEach(element =>
    console.log('#' + data.results.id +
     " - " + data.results.species_guess +
      ' (' + data.results.observed_on_details.date + ')')
  );
}
```

Replace "data.results" with "element"

```
function observationSummary2(data) {
    data.results.forEach(element =>
    console.log('#' + element.id +
     " - " + element.species_guess +
      ' (' + element.observed_on_details.date + ')')
  );
}
```

More info about "forEach()" here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach